# How to use multiple ng-apps with multiple controllers

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Here i have two ng-apps and there controllers.Here is i want to access controller value in other controller with there different ng-apps .But i am getting error.please help me out.

Thank you.

Html:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="service.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
        <div id="myDiv1">
            <div  ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="CalcController">
              <p>Enter a number: <input type="number" ng-model="number" />
              <button ng-click="multiply()">X<sup>2</sup></button>
              <p>Result 1: {{result}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div ng-app="myDiv2">
            <div ng-controller="MyController2">
              <p>Enter a number: <input type="number" ng-model="numberSecond" />
              <button ng-click="multiplyValue()">X<sup>2</sup></button>
              <p>Result 2: {{result2}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Controller.js:

```
angular.module('myReuseableMod',[]).factory('$myReuseableSrvc',function() {
  var factory = {};
  factory.multiply = function(a) {
    return a * a
  }

  return factory;
});


var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", ["myReuseableMod"]);
mainApp.controller('CalcController', ['$scope', '$myReuseableSrvc',function($scope, $myReuseableSrvc) {

  $scope.multiply = function() {
    $scope.result = $myReuseableSrvc.multiply($scope.number);
  }
  $scope.aB=function()
  {
      alert("hiii");
  }

}]);

var mainApp2 = angular.module("mainApp2", ['mainApp']);
mainApp2.controller('MyController2',['CalcController' '$scope','$myReuseableSrvc',function(CalcController,$scope,  $myReuseableSrvc) {
  console.log('init B');
  $scope.multiplyValue = function() {
      $scope.result2 = $myReuseableSrvc.multiply($scope.numberSecond);
         CalcController.aB(); //here i want to acess controller 'CalcController' method.
  }
}]);
```

Here is my plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/6QyDuV330YlgXy16S2YX?p=preview

Comment: you dont have able to use multiple ngapps in one html page

Comment: if want to use it values make your own module and inject and use this module services in diffrent controllers

Comment: But i have two different pages and both pages are having different ng-apps and controller then what to do..please help me..

Comment: i need to attach both pages with common factory service ...both pages are related and i have to use method of one page in another.. please Edit my plunker if possible..thank you..

Comment: sorry dude angular not allowed you to use two ng-app in one html page you have create another html page

Comment: this was only an example..but in my project i have two pages and both are related to each other...

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually bootstrap them.

See :

> Only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML document. The first ngApp found in the document will be used to define the root element to auto-bootstrap as an application  http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngApp

Comment: Here is have used angular bootstrap for ng-app ..but still i can't access first controller's function.please help me..